# method for SelectValueChanged in combo box returns nothing

Tags: c#, wpf

I have connected a combo box to a database of all countries, i now want whatever country is chosen to be displayed in a message box but the method does nothing.

here is my code

```
    private void MainWindow_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String cname = this.worldCbx.Text;
        MessageBox.Show(cname);
    }
```

i cant seem to be able to acess the .Text value, i had another task to change the combobox text to "Select Country :" on startup which wouldnt work either

The code was :

```
private void MainWindow_Load(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

     this.worldCbx.Text = "Select Country : ";
}
```

Comment: combobox doesnt have text property. U need to worldCbx.SelectedItem to get the selected item and cast it to appropriate type. Also when u set a item as selected item that item should be present in combobox

Comment: SelectedValueChanged is an event of the Winforms ComboBox. Are you sure you're using WPF?